# How to replace a letter by index

Tags: python

Made a hangman, not sure if theres a better way of writing it but im new to Python so this is what i thought of.

When i have a word to guess e.g. Programming, how do I allow the code to find the second "m" in word and place it in the word template

```
word_selection = ("python", "coding", "language", "programming")
selected_word = random.choice(word_selection)
print(selected_word)
def hangman_game(word, guess_limit, guess_count):
    letter_template = len(word) * " _"
    fail_count = 0

    while guess_count < guess_limit:
        print("")
        letter_guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()

        if len(letter_guess) > 1:
            print("Please enter 1 character/ Letter")

        elif letter_guess in letter_template:
            print("You already guessed this letter.")

        elif letter_guess in word:
            print(letter_guess, " is in the word")

            letter_index = word.index(letter_guess)
            letter_template = letter_template[:letter_index*2] + " " + letter_guess + letter_template[(letter_index + 1)*2:]

            print(letter_template)
            guess_count += 1



        else:
            print(letter_guess, " is not in the word")
            fail_count += 1
            if fail_count == 1:
                print("""







       _________
            """)

            if fail_count == 2:
                print("""





      |
      |
      |_________
            """)
            if fail_count == 3:
                print("""

      |    
      |    
      |    
      |    
      |
      |
      |_________
            """)
            if fail_count == 4:
                print("""
       ______
      |    
      |    
      |    
      |    
      |
      |
      |_________
            """)
            if fail_count == 5:
                print("""
       _______
      |       |
      |    
      |    
      |    
      |
      |
      |_________
            """)
            if fail_count == 6:
                print("""
       _______
      |       |
      |       O
      |    
      |    
      |
      |
      |_________
            """)
            if fail_count == 7:
                print("""
       _______
      |       |
      |       O
      |      -|-
      |    
      |
      |
      |_________
            """)
            if fail_count == 8:
                print("""
       _______
      |       |
      |       O
      |      -|-
      |      /
      |
      |
      |_________
            """)
            if fail_count == 9:
                print ("""
       _______
      |       |
      |       O
      |      -|-
      |      /|
      |
      |
      |_________
            """)

            if fail_count == 9:
                print("Out of guesses! The man has been hung.")
                print("")
                print("The word was", word)
                break
    else:
        print("You guessed the word")

hangman_game(selected_word, len(selected_word), 0)
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Im getting: 

Guess a letter: o
o  is in the word
 _ _ _ _ _ _
4
o_o_o_o_o_o_
Guess a letter:

Comment: It should be "_ _ _ o _ " instead of "o_o_o_o_o_o_ "

Comment: the code is replacing all the occurrences with `letter_guess`

Comment: I'd suggest you to use a `list` instead of string

Comment: Could you help me write this in the code?

Comment: Please try it yourself. Use `word = list(word)` before while loop and update the while loop with list manipulations instead of string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of:

```
print(letter_template.replace(letter_template[letter_index], letter_guess))
```

for peplacing a character from a certain index use:

```
letter_template =letter_template[:letter_index*2] + " "+letter_guess + letter_template[(letter_index + 1)*2:]
```

your code:

```
def hangman_game(word, guess_limit, guess_count, letter_guess, out_of_guesses):
    letter_template = len(word) * " _" # this part should be outside of the while loop becouse you will define empty pattern every itteration

    if letter_guess != word and not out_of_guesses:
        while guess_count < guess_limit:
            letter_guess = input("Guess a letter: ")
            if letter_guess in word:
                print(letter_guess, " is in the word")

                letter_index = word.index(letter_guess)

                #print(letter_template.replace(letter_template[letter_index], letter_guess))
                letter_template =letter_template[:letter_index*2] + " " + letter_guess + letter_template[(letter_index + 1)*2:]
                print(letter_template)
                guess_count += 1
            else:
                print(letter_guess, " is not in the word")

hangman_game("python", 5, 1, "", False)
```

output:

```
Guess a letter: t
t  is in the word
 _ _ t _ _ _
Guess a letter: h
h  is in the word
 _ _ t h _ _
Guess a letter: p
p  is in the word
 p _ t h _ _
Guess a letter:
```

EDIT:

```
def hangman_game(word, guess_limit, guess_count, letter_guess, out_of_guesses):
letter_template = len(word) * " _" # this part should be outside of the while loop becouse you will define empty pattern every itteration
fail_count = 0
if letter_guess != word and not out_of_guesses:
    while guess_count < guess_limit:
        letter_guess = input("Guess a letter: ")
        if letter_guess in word:
            print(letter_guess, " is in the word")

            letter_index = word.index(letter_guess)

            #print(letter_template.replace(letter_template[letter_index], letter_guess))
            letter_template =letter_template[:letter_index*2] + " " + letter_guess + letter_template[(letter_index + 1)*2:]
            print(letter_template)
            guess_count += 1
        else:
            print(letter_guess, " is not in the word")
            fail_count += 1
            if fail_count == 5:
                print("You missed the letter 5 times! Game Over!")
                return
    else:
        print ("You guessed the word")
```

hangman_game("python", len("python"), 0, "", False)

output:

```
Guess a letter: p
p  is in the word
 p _ _ _ _ _
Guess a letter: o
o  is in the word
 p _ _ _ o _
Guess a letter: a
a  is not in the word
Guess a letter: a
a  is not in the word
Guess a letter: a
a  is not in the word
Guess a letter: a
a  is not in the word
Guess a letter: a
a  is not in the word
You missed the letter 5 times! Game Over!
```

Comment: I want to add a line where if user completes the word and it should display "You guessed the word" - Could you help with the answer?

Comment: One more thing, I also need help on adding a guess limit e.g 5 guesses. Could you help on that also?

Comment: just call your function like :hangman_game("python", 5, 0, "", False)

Comment: but in your edit, you put : hangman_game("python", len("python"), 0, "", False)

you set the guess_limit as "len("python")

Comment: sorry,i meant I wanted a guess limit for when the user guesses wrong e.g. user is allowed to guess wrong 5 times before they are out of guesses and game is over

Comment: nice, thanks! I will try myself to add the each part of hangman image when user gets a guess wrong. What i struggle with is where to place the code :/... I'll prob be back for your help!

Comment: Editted my original post, could you help me please?

Comment: Basically, if i have a word "Programming" to guess and I guess the letter "m" once, it adds the guess count but then when i guess the letter "m" again as there is 2 m's i think it recognizes the first m rather than the second. Same applies for all words with a double character in them

Comment: Any helpers on this?